# How to use numba njit on dictionaried with list of arrays as values

Tags: dictionary, numba, jit

I am trying to learn how to use python dictionaries with numba `njit`. In this regard, we must convert the pythonic dictionary items to numba compatible one. I got stuck in this step when working on a dictionary in which values were list of arrays. The following example can reproduce the problem:

```
sample_dict = {'size_0': [np.array([0.021, 0.022]), np.array([0.03, 0.008])],
               'size_1': [np.array([0.031]), np.array([0.036, 0.003])],
               'size_2': [np.array([], dtype=np.float64), np.array([0.043])]}
num_ = 2



String = nb.types.unicode_type
ValueArray = nb.float64[::1]

ValueList = nb.types.ListType(ValueArray)
ValueDict = nb.types.DictType(String, ValueList)

# DictValue = nb.types.Tuple([ValueArray])
# ValueDict = nb.types.DictType(String, DictValue)

# DictValue = nb.types.Tuple([nb.types.List(ValueArray, reflected=True)])
# ValueDict = nb.types.DictType(String, DictValue)

sample_nb = nb.typed.typeddict.Dict.empty(String, ValueArray)
for key, value in sample_dict.items():
    sample_nb[key] = value.copy()
    # sample_nb[key] = nb.types.List(value)


@nb.njit(ValueDict, nb.int_)
def nbTest(sample_dict, num_):
    ii = 1
    for i in range(num_):
        for j in sample_dict.values():
            ii += len(j[i])


nbTest(sample_nb, num_)
```

I've get different errors since I have tried various ways, but the most happened one was:

> No implementation of function Function()
> found for signature:
>
> setitem(DictType[unicode_type,array(float64, 1d, C)]<iv=None>, unicode_type, reflected list(array(float64, 1d, C))<iv=None>)

How to prepare such dictionaries for using by numba `njit`? Is there any limitation if one of dictionary values have just one array (not as this example which all dictionary values contain 2 arrays)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue comes from two point: the type is not valid in the dict as it is `ValueArray` while it should be `ValueList` and the reflected list that cannot be copied into the dict using a basic assignment. For the second point `nb.typed.typedlist.List` can be used to fix that. Note that `nb.types.List` is a type while `nb.typed.typedlist.List` is used to create instances. Here is the resulting code:

```py
String = nb.types.unicode_type
ValueArray = nb.float64[::1]

ValueList = nb.types.ListType(ValueArray)
ValueDict = nb.types.DictType(String, ValueList)

# DictValue = nb.types.Tuple([ValueArray])
# ValueDict = nb.types.DictType(String, DictValue)

# DictValue = nb.types.Tuple([nb.types.List(ValueArray, reflected=True)])
# ValueDict = nb.types.DictType(String, DictValue)

sample_nb = nb.typed.typeddict.Dict.empty(String, ValueList)
for key, value in sample_dict.items():
    sample_nb[key] = nb.typed.typedlist.List(value.copy())
    # sample_nb[key] = nb.types.List(value)
```